# android: how to set the "user-permission" within the "MainActivity.java" file

Tags: java, android, user-permissions, wifip2p

I am developing an android app that is implementing the ***Wifi P2P framework*** ...the user-permissions are set on the `Manifest.xml` as follow:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

.. and, I believe, the P2P service is enabled once I start my app (and on resume) ... 
and I do not want that anymore ...i.e.: enabling the P2P service automatically ..

I want to be able to set a `ToggleButton` that enables or disables these permissions from within my `MainActivity.java` file. here is my `ToggleButton` code:

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
   Button btnDiscover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiscover);
   boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
   if (on) {
      // Enable the P2P service 

   } else {

   }
}
```

How can I do this  ?

P.S: I am new to android and Java programming

Comment: why wouldn't you simply put the permission in the manifest ?

Comment: @njzk2: they're already there in the Manifest at the moment, however I want the user himself to be able to control "enabling/disabling" the services when he wants to ... sadly, i guess, and according to bofredo below, Google doesn't allow this for security reasons ..

Answer (score 1):

No. The user needs to be informed about the permissions while installing the application. Askling them at runtime would be a security risk. And google doesn't like possible security-leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the permissions dynamically...Use a **boolean variable**. If it true proceed other wise don't proceed further...the variable default value is false